# how to update multiple rows in ms access from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc, python-db-api

I'm trying to execute this update query from columns in a pandas dataframe:

```
sql = "UPDATE tblhis_ventas SET portabilidad = '%s' WHERE (contrato = '%s' and estado = '%s') " % (
    df['portabilidad'], df['contrato'], df['estado']
)

cursor.execute(sql)
```

The query isn't executed and no error is displayed.

My dataframe looks like below:

[image: Data Table Screeshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MS Access (specifically its disk-level Jet/ACE Engine not the GUI .exe program) is not supported with SQLAlchemy to allow for the [`pandas.to_sql()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method which ideally you can push your dataframe to a temp table in database to run an `UPDATE final INNER JOIN temp ...` query to update final table, a much faster route than iterating across rows.

Fortunately, MS Access' Jet/ACE Engine can query csv files as if they were tables where you specify the file's path and then name of csv file. Hence, consider exporting dataframe [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), then create a temp table using the [Make-Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5877z8t.aspx) query, and finally run the update join query. Below `try/except` is used to drop the table if exists (since `IF EXISTS` command is not available in MS Access SQL).

```
df.to_csv('C:\Path\To\CSV\Output.csv', index=False)

try:
   cursor.execute("SELECT * INTO tblhis_ventas_Temp" +\
                  " FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);Database=C:\Path\To\CSV].Output.csv")
   conn.commit()

   cursor.execute("UPDATE tblhis_ventas f INNER JOIN tblhis_ventas_Temp t" + \
                   " ON f.contrato = t.contrato AND f.estado = t.estado" + \
                   " SET f. portabilidad = t.portabilidad")
   conn.commit()

except Exception as e:    
    if 'already exists' in str(e):
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE tblhis_ventas_Temp")
        conn.commit()
    else:
        print(e)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

And no, we cannot directly use CSV file in `UPDATE` query (bypassing temp table process) as the csv is a read-only and not *updateable* recordset. Interestingly, you can use CSV in an `INSERT...SELECT`.

Comment: it works!. It's very fast. I didn't know the temporary csv files in ms access.  I am very grateful to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate rows, and update one by one:

```
sql = 'UPDATE tblhis_ventas SET portabilidad = ? WHERE contrato = ? and estado = ?'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql, [row['portabilidad'], row['contrato'], row['estado']])
```

Comment: it works!. The problem is that the table is over 10k and it takes more than 10 minutes to update one field, i need 10 fields more ;). Is there a fast way?

Comment: @calobeto, Could you show the whole code? Without know which data is selected, and what operation are done with `df`, I can't tell you how to improve it, or even tell you whether it's possible.